# Django tutorial choice_set

Tags: django, django-models

From the Django tutorial:

I've defined my models as follows:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return self.question
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Where is choice_set defined and how does this work?

```
>>> p = Poll.objects.get(pk=1)

# Display any choices from the related object set -- none so far.
>>> p.choice_set.all()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how deep an explanation you want, but Django defines it for you when you do `poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)`.

[You can read here about it.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects)

Comment: What is this python feature called, where it can generate methods dynamically?

Comment: It's called metaclass programming and you can read about it here: http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2003/04/17/metaclasses.html - In Django it get's done when you inherit from `models.Model`.

Answer (score 0):

choice_set wasn't defined anywhere.

Django creates API accessors for the “other” side of the relationship – the link from the related model to the model that defines the relationship. For example, a Poll object p has access to a list of all related Choice objects via the choice_set attribute: p.choice_set.all().

So choice_set. Where choice is your Choice model in lowercase and _set is kind of Django Manager Tool.

In details, you can read [right here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) .